# Form in modal submitting twice

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I would like to show you my code and try to see why it is sending the form twice after the first submit.

I am using a class "save" and I check the form id and submit it, but after I save a register and try to save a new one and this new one will go trough twice.

My modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form_organization" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title info">New organization</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                     
           <form class="form-horizontal" id="new_save" name="new_save">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name_company">Name</label>  
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" id="name_company" name="name_company" class="form-control input-md" required="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <button class="btn btn-success save" type="submit" id="comapny_save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save</button>  
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Close </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery/JS Function:

```
var $save = $(".save");

 $save.on("click", function () {                            
    var id_form = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
    var id_modal = $(this).closest(".modal").attr('id');
        submitForm(id_form, id_modal);

});

function submitForm(form, modal) {
    $("#"+form).submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var action = form.substring(0, form.indexOf("_"));
                var table = form.replace(action + "_", "");

                $.post('./include/save.php?table=' + table + '&action=' + action, {
                            dataForm: $("#"+form).serialize()
                                }, function (data) {
                                    if (data == "success") {
                                        $table.bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                                            url: './include/refresh.php'
                                        });                                        

                                        $("#" + modal).modal('toggle');
                    $("#" + form)[0].reset();
                                        dlgSuccess();

                                    } else {
                                        dlgError();
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        }
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You set up the submit event handler *after* the first click. Thereafter, each click registers an additional submit handler (and additional AJAX request).

Instead, forget about the click event and just register one submit event handler.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    var id_form = $(this).attr(id);
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url, function(result) { });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action for a button of `type=submit`...

```
<button class="btn btn-success save" type="submit" id="comapny_save">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save
</button>
```

...is to submit the form.  The easy solution would be to set the [type to a button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).  I am personally a fan of doing as little to javascript events as possible, especially when it can be remedied by *correct* html.

```
<button class="btn btn-success save" type="button" id="comapny_save">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Save
</button>
```

> ps: comapny_save does not appear to be spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Call off your submit through `$('#form').off('submit')`
And then turning it on again

Like so

```
$('#form').off('submit').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //do something
});
```